# How to find dockerhub image tags using given docker image ID (sha)?

Tags: docker, dockerhub

I have a server running docker containers for years. Containers was started from dockerhub images by tags, which do not include a specific version:

```
$ docker ps | grep redis
0123456789ab   redis:alpine    "docker-entrypoint.s…"   19 months ago   Up 19 months   6379/tcp   redis

$ docker images redis
REPOSITORY   TAG       IMAGE ID       CREATED         SIZE
redis        alpine    5c08f13a2b92   20 months ago   32.4MB
```

So the image with sha `5c08f13a2b92` was pulled 20 month ago from dockerhub as `redis:alpine` tag. Today `redis:alpine` tag definitely pointing to another image (sha). And today I can't find out, which dockerhub image is related to my pulled docker image.

How can I know, which tag on dockerhub with exactly version (something like `redis:6.2.6-alpine`), or which tags (all of them), is/are related to my pulled image, if I know only it's sha?

Comment: In the unlikely event that someone is looking for information about the same sha `5c08f13a2b92`: I went through dockerhub tags randomly, was lucky and found that this sha matches the tag `6.2-alpine3.14`. (But it doesn't answers to my question: how not to iterate over all dockerhub tags manually.)